# change the page to write protected

Tags: c, linux, struct, kernel, paging

I'm doing a project in linux kernel and I want to find/write a function in the kernel that takes a `struct page` and change it to write protected.

I found this function, that takes a `pte` of a page and changes the page to wrprotect:

```
static inline pte_t pte_wrprotect(pte_t pte)
```

(in [x86/include/asm/pgtable](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable.h?v=2.6.34#L167))

but I don't know how to get the `pte_t` of page from its `struct page`. 
I searched in the documentation of this struct, but I didn't find.

Can anyone explain me how to get the `pte_t` of page from its `struct page`?

Thanks

Comment: This link has a [tutorial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CFUQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cse.psu.edu%2F~anand%2Fspring01%2Flinux%2Fmemory.ppt&ei=dkYnUtjwE-a_igLN54HYAw&usg=AFQjCNF9UPBYHS0cSQve3WtD4OIyTP7-bw&sig2=Ko73UvgQxW_b7BXbmFEZHg&bvm=bv.51495398,d.cGE) that might help

Comment: This [one](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html) is also good